# How do I invoke a method with two arguments (where one of them is params)?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, parameters

I have a newbie question: How do I invoke the following method:

```
public void Download(MyEnum aStrategy, params string [] strings)
```

I have tried:

```
Download(MyEnum.All, new string [] {"a", "b", "c"})
```

but have not had any success.

Comment: It should be correct. The alternative way (and more clean) is `Download(MyEnum.All, "a", "b", "c");`

Comment: maybe its because i have nother method defined - Download(params string [] strings) ?

Comment: I don't think that will make a difference.  Can you post details of the exception?

Comment: funny thing ... i rebuilded again and the error is gone. Looks like i have problem in project dependencies making confusion. Thanx anyway guys.

Comment: params is essentially for the situation where you want to call it like this `Download(Enum.All, "1","2","3")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Download(MyEnum.All, "a", "b", "c")
```

Your code should work to, but the above is "more correct".

Comment: since the problem was not with code but with compiler im gonna go with your anwser :)